# ReactJS <Errors> component not defined?

Tags: reactjs

So I am trying to use the `Errors` component in my code, taken from
https://davidkpiano.github.io/react-redux-form/docs/api/Errors.html

But VSCode is telling me that `Errors` is not defined, so I tried importing it like `import { Errors } from 'reactstrap';` which makes the error go away but when running the website with `yarn start` I get `"Attempted import error: 'Errors' is not exported from 'reactstrap'."`

Any ideas?

Comment: reactstrap It has no component called Errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Errors` is provided in the `react-redux-form` package, so you need to import that module from the place where it's defined:

```js
import { Errors } from 'react-redux-form';
```